# Not able to export CSV file from MySQL data by using following code

Tags: php

When I click on button to export file it just redirects to the
 export.php file given as href to the button and does nt download the
 file

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT d_domain, d_purchase_price, d_selling_price FROM 
domains";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "data.csv";
    $output = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    $fields = array('Domain Name', 'Purchase Price', 'Selling Price');
    fputcsv($output, $fields, $delimiter);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $lineData = array($row['d_domain'], $row['d_purchase_price'],
            $row['d_selling_price']);
        fputcsv($output, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
    fseek($output, 0);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= data.csv');

    fpassthru($f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rewind` before seek also in `fpassthru($f)` you're passing wrong file handle

Try this code

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT d_domain, d_purchase_price, d_selling_price FROM 
domains";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "data.csv";
    $output = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    $fields = array('Domain Name', 'Purchase Price', 'Selling Price');
    fputcsv($output, $fields, $delimiter);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $lineData = array($row['d_domain'], $row['d_purchase_price'],
            $row['d_selling_price']);
        fputcsv($output, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
    rewind($output);
    fseek($output, 0);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= data.csv');

    fpassthru($output); // You're using $f
}
```

Comment: @Mansi try with $output = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');

Comment: Open the stream in the r+ mode

Comment: @Mansi i have added another code.. you can use that also.. Also can you please provide the error you're getting or what is happening when you run your code.. Provide more details

Answer (score 0):

If it still not working then might be some issue with the php://memory usage in your server.. might be it will restricted.. You can also try with php://output this will definitely work

Try this code

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$query = "SELECT d_domain, d_purchase_price, d_selling_price FROM 
domains";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "data.csv";

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $fields = array('Domain Name', 'Purchase Price', 'Selling Price');
    fputcsv($output, $fields, $delimiter);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $lineData = array($row['d_domain'], $row['d_purchase_price'],
            $row['d_selling_price']);
        fputcsv($output, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }
    //rewind($output);
    //fseek($output, 0);



    //fpassthru($output); // You're using $f

    fclose($output);
}
```